# Elaborate a function parameter as static variable

Tags: c

I was wondering how to make a function consider a given parameter as a static variable. For example, i tried, without success, to generate hailstone numbers:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int hailstone(int);
int n;                            /* n is an extern variable*/

int main(){
    hailstone(n);
    return 0;
}

int hailstone(int n){
    static int m = n;            /*not possible because n is not constant*/
    if(m % 2 == 0 && m != 1)
        hailstone(m /= 2);
    else if(m != 1)
        hailstone((m *= 3) + 1);
    else
        exit(0);                 /*Is the use of exit() correct, in this case?*/
    return 0;
 }
```

I would like to use a static variable to elaborate n. Otherwise, each recursive call would operate on the whole parameter `n`, thus going on endless, never reaching the case base.

Few questions:

1. Does this idea represent a feasible approach to the problem?
2. Does this idea represent a *reasonable/effective* approach to the problem?
3. Is `exit(0)` used correctly, in a similar case?

Comment: `static int m; m = n;` is possible, however.

Comment: Using a global variable in a recursive function defeats the point of recursion, so you are definitely need to rethink your solution. In any event, your function doesn't show any base case (other than 0, which cannot be reached). What is the base case, in your opinion, and why do you think that recursion won't reach it?

Comment: @ricie, is the case base not represented by 'm < 1'? Perhaps, since the final result should be 1, 'm == 1' could be a better base case, you are right. Also, I was precisely wandering on how surpass the problem of the global variable.

Comment: The usual way for a recursive function to progress toward the base case is for it to pass different arguments when it calls itself than were passed to it.  Static variables are not necessary for that.

Comment: @Worice  The function does not make sense It always returns 0 if it returns.:).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you are right, thanks for point it out!

Comment: This looks like the Collatz sequence in disguise.  Or the Collatz hypothesis.  Using `exit()` is probably not appropriate. It isn’t incorrect in the sense of being invalid C. You never print anything or use a computed result. That makes it fairly pointless as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a static variable for this.  Just pass in the new value to operate on and use that.  Also, the value 1 is your base case, so check for that to stop the recursion, and print the value of `n` so you can actually see what's going on.

```
void hailstone(int n){
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    if(n % 2 == 0 && n > 1) {
        hailstone(n/2);
    } else if(n > 1) {
        hailstone((n*3) + 1);
    }
 }
```

Given that this function could go on for quite a few iterations, a recursive solution could end up causing a stack overflow.  Better to go with an iterative solution:

```
void hailstone(int n){
    while (n > 1) {
        printf("n=%d\n", n);
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n/2;
        } else {
            n = (n*3) + 1;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks to @rici comment i adjusted the case base, thanks.

Comment: I will make a little of practice of your code. Thanks for the double example. Recursion is still not so intuitive for me, hence being able to compare it with an iterative approach is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the recursive algorithm for hailstorm, there's no need for `static`

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void hailstone(unsigned int n)
{
    assert(n>0);
    printf("%u\n", n);
    if ( n == 1 )
       return;
    if( n & 1 ) {
         hailstone(3*n + 1);
    }
    else {
         hailstone(n >> 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    hailstone(5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, it is giving me a good insight on the problem!